# Why does this `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'] fail?

Tags: php

What am I missing here? This is my PHP file:

```
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["address"] = $_POST["address1"];
$_SESSION["phone"] = $_POST["phone"];
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
$_SESSION["uname"] = $_POST["uname"];
```

Comment: which is the form which sends data?

Comment: check whether isset($_POST["name"])

Comment: Is the diffence `address` vs. `address1` on purpose? Otherwise, some more information on the type of error you are experiencing would be helpful.

Comment: The assignment should work. What lets you think it’s not working?

Comment: use `session_start();` at top of php file.

Comment: first try to print that $_POST has the data or not? try `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: yes., i have start session at top. and i want to display this sessions on 2nd file.. is it possible..?

Comment: @MadanSingh : Yes...you need to start session at the second page also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check you POST values. `print_r($_POST);`
2. Start session at the top of the page `session_start();`

Comment: yes., i have start session at top. and i want to display this sessions on 2nd file.. is it possible..?

Comment: @MadanSingh : Why is it unchecked  ?

Comment: okay now..?? really its right answer..just im new to SOflw.. so just test all option..

Comment: @MadanSingh : Ok..cool :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have started session using session_start() on the page you want to use the session.

You need to use session_start() on every page you want to use $_SESSION otherwise $_SESSION will no be accessible on that page.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stored values in session :

```
 $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST["name"];
 $_SESSION["address"] = $_POST["address1"];
```

in other page(file) write session_start() at the top & access session variables as:

```
 echo  isset($_SESSION["name"])?$_SESSION["name"]:'';
```

thats it!